# Passing List of Objects not working in Web API Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

If I pass single object like below, My controller is showing the data.

My C# library project.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, myRequestObject, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

My Controller looks like this.

```
public async Task<Response> Execute(Request request)
    {
        this.Logger.Debug("Initializing Controller");

        return await Task.Run(() => ExecuteRequest());
    }
```

The above code is working and I am receiving the data from C# library.

I want to pass list of objects like this

```
var objectList = new List<RequestObject> { myRequestObject}
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, objectList , new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

And I want my controller like this.

```
public async Task<Response> Execute(List<Request> request)
    {
        this.Logger.Debug("Initializing Controller");

        return await Task.Run(() => ExecuteRequest());
    }
```

Passing list is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `[FromBody]` to your argument

```
public async Task<Response> Execute([FromBody] List<Request> request)
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider ticking it as _right_.